# How to show different backgrounds at a time in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

i am new developer on andengine. i am making a game of bike racer, where i want to move my background instead of my bike. so how can i use two 3 background if 1 background is complete then start second one and when it complete then start third? How should i do for it please tell me to solve this problem.

Comment: Use  Parallax scrolling class for this

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tiles in your background?
I got this snippet of code from : [This very useful tutorial](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/tiled-game-t4331.html)

```
    switch(lDirection) {
                case RIGHT:
                    int RightAnimTiles[] = {WorldActivity.RIGHT_CENTER_TILE - 1,
                            WorldActivity.RIGHT_CENTER_TILE,
                            WorldActivity.RIGHT_CENTER_TILE + 1,
                            WorldActivity.RIGHT_CENTER_TILE};
                    animate(WorldActivity.WALK_ANIMATE_DURATION, RightAnimTiles, -1);
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    int DownAnimTiles[] = {WorldActivity.DOWN_CENTER_TILE - 1,
                            WorldActivity.DOWN_CENTER_TILE,
                            WorldActivity.DOWN_CENTER_TILE + 1,
                            WorldActivity.DOWN_CENTER_TILE};
                    animate(WorldActivity.WALK_ANIMATE_DURATION, DownAnimTiles, -1);
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    int LeftAnimTiles[] = {WorldActivity.LEFT_CENTER_TILE - 1,
                            WorldActivity.LEFT_CENTER_TILE,
                            WorldActivity.LEFT_CENTER_TILE + 1,
                            WorldActivity.LEFT_CENTER_TILE};
                    animate(WorldActivity.WALK_ANIMATE_DURATION, LeftAnimTiles, -1);
                    break;
                case UP:
                    int UpAnimTiles[] = {WorldActivity.UP_CENTER_TILE - 1,
                            WorldActivity.UP_CENTER_TILE,
                            WorldActivity.UP_CENTER_TILE + 1,
                            WorldActivity.UP_CENTER_TILE};
                    animate(WorldActivity.WALK_ANIMATE_DURATION, UpAnimTiles, -1);
                    break;
            default:
                break;

            }
```